# How to redirect subdomain to other port using Apache2 server with reverse proxy

Tags: debian, proxy, port

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have, in my home server running Debian 8, installed Deluged (torrent client) and a web UI to control it. I can access this web UI using the address :`http://example.com:8112/`.
I have Apache2 configured with virtual hosts on the same server.
What I want to do is access this web UI using `http://torrent.example.com/` without having to enter the port number. So, I have already set an A record on my domain name for this subdomain, and it is working proberly.

After some research I have found that this is possible using a reverse proxy. I have read about it, and created a new file called torrent.example.com.conf in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/ folder.

Here is the content of this file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName torrent.example.com
        ServerAlias www.torrent.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8112/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8112/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have of course enabled the needed modules in Apache2, and the site that I added in sites-enabled.
What if want to do with this is that when I access `http://torrent.example.com/`, it still shows this URL address but shows the web UI at `http://example.com:8112/`.

According to what I have read this should work properly.

My problem is that it doesn't work as expected, when I access the URL it only redirects me to my main site `http://example.com/`, just as it would if I hadn't setup the VirtualHost. This is why I'm coming here for help, I have read lots of other threads and have tried many different settings but none of them seem to solve my problem.

Some of this explanation might not be clear or there might be some obvious mistakes, sorry but I'm only beginning at web servers and have a lot to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be due to a virtualhost clash. Do you have any other virtual hosts enabled, perhaps the default one? If you do try to disable them temporarily to see if that helps. Note that you should also set `ProxyRequests Off` for security reasons - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests .

Comment: Thanks @piit79 for the tip about `ProxyRequests`. Unfortunately though I tried disabling all other virtual hosts and it still redirected me. I think that this is due to a mistake of mine when using `RedirectPermanent` instead of using a normal redirect (as a temporary solution).
So, I tried with another browser and this time it just wouldn't load the web page.
EDIT : For some reason it suddenly started working, I'll just have to search how to prevent the browser from automatically redirecting but I guess that this is done with cache. Thanks for your help though.